# How to write a Jackson pojo class for a json object like a javascript object literal

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Modules class that contains a list of Module, the normal jackson json would look like:

```
 {  
       "modules" : [

          {
                "name" :  "module1" ,
                "file" : "file1"
            },

           {
              "name" : "module2" ,
              "file" : "file2" 
          }
        ]
    }
```

But I need the json file to be like this:

```
{  
   "modules" : {

      "module1" : {
           "file" : "file1"
        },

      "module2" : {
          "file" : "file2" 
      }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to configure/construct the pojo classes to achieve what I want without a custom deserializer?
Thanks

Comment: can we see the current Module class ?

Comment: Hi the Module class only contains a "name" and a "file" String fields. The problem is solved by using a map. Thanks for participating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done anything with Jackson, but if you store the objects in a `HashMap<String, ObjectType>` that might do it. Otherwise yes, a custom deserializer would be necessary.

Comment: Right! exactly! How did I miss that! Thanks.